# jquery mobile how to keep indismissible popup after page change

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, popup

I like to achieve chaining popup (dialog). JQM does not support chaining popups.
First open a popup(dismissible:false). From the popup, open a dialog page.
The problem is: after closing the dialog page, the popup disappears.

```
<div id="popup" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">

  <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>Global Menu</li>
    <li><a href="#demo-intro">Intro Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#other-page">Other Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third-page">Third Page</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>

  <a href="#page2" data-rel="dialog">Dialog</a>

</div>

<div id="page1" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">

    <h1> Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup">Menu</a>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">

    <h1>Dialog Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the indismissible popup after dialog page closes? Thanks.

Comment: What is the pattern to achieve chaining popup or dialogs?

Comment: You can chain popups by using the simpledialog2  jqm plugin: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/